# fgets reading in spaces when there are none

Tags: c, fgets

Using `fgets()` to read in strings.

But the print statement that prints the size prints out 4 when my input is a 3 character string "abc".

This ruins my methods completely because it adds a space to the char array making arrange not work.

Input file:

```
2
abc
bca
```

I'm sure there is no space after the strings.

```
int main(){

  FILE * inF;
  inF = fopen ("input2.txt", "r");


  //Find number of Strings
  int numWords = 0;
  fscanf(inF, "%d", &numWords);
  printf("%d\n", numWords);

  int i = 0;
  int counter = 0;
  char string[10000];


  //Run fgets so it starts at second line
  fgets(string, 20, inF);

  while(i< numWords) {

    string[10000] = 0;
    fgets(string, 20, inF);
    printf("char: %s", string);

    //find and print permutations
    counter = strlen(string);
    printf("size: %d\n", counter);
    arrange(string, 0, counter - 1);

    i++;
    }

  return 0;

  }
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: There probably are no space after your characters. There are however a newline , if you don't need the newline, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The first `fscanf` reads the number, but leaves the newline. So when you later call `fgets` it is this empty line that `fgets` reads.

Use only `fgets` to get complete lines, and if you need to use a `scanf` like function then use `sscanf` on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `fscanf()` and `fgets()`.

Read a whole line for the first line, then use `sscanf()` to parse out the number from that line, before continuining with more `fgets()` to read remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

You may print what's in the buffer `string[]` after `fgets`, like this:

```
...
while(i< numWords) {

string[10000] = 0; // !!! Do you mean string[9999] = 0;
fgets(string, 20, inF);
printf("char: %s", string);

// add printf here
for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    printf("%02X ", (unsigned char)string[j]);
printf("\n");

...
}
```

and you would see the result like this:

```
2
char: abc
61 62 63 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
size: 4
char: bca
62 63 61 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
size: 4
```

As you can see, there is a `0A`, i.e., `\n`, after every `fgets`. Then it would be obvious why the size is `4`.

```
$ man fgets
    ...
    If  a  newline  is  read, it is stored into the buffer.
    ...
```

So you may have to remove the newline manually.